# Find $[\mathbb Q (\sqrt[4]{-5}, \xi^2 ) : \mathbb Q ]$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, group-extensions

$\xi = e^{\frac{\pi}4i}$

$K=\mathbb Q (\sqrt[4]{5} \xi , \sqrt[4]{5} \xi^3 , \sqrt[4]{5} \xi^5 , \sqrt[4]{5} \xi^7 )= \mathbb Q (\sqrt[4]{5} \xi , \xi^2)=\mathbb Q (\sqrt[4]{-5}, \xi^2 )$

I am pretty sure these above equalities hold.

$L=\mathbb Q (\sqrt[4]{-5})$, $J=\mathbb Q (\xi^2)$

Also let $Q = \mathbb Q$

$[K:Q]=[K: L] \cdot [L:Q]$ and $[K:Q]=[K: J] \cdot [J:Q]$

$[L:Q]=4$ and $[J:Q]=2$, which I am pretty confident with. So we have:

$[K:Q]=4[K: L]  $ and $[K:Q]=2[K: J] $

Can someone tell me how to work out either $[K:J]$ or $[K:L]$ (in a lot of detail please).

Comment: $\xi^2 = e^{{\pi\over 2}i} = i$

Comment: @ViniciusM. I see thanks. Any ideas on how to work it out?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the tower of fields $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb Q(i) \subseteq \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5) \subseteq \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5})$ and show that these are strict inclusions. It then follows that $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q] = 8$. It is obvious that $i\notin \mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt5\notin \mathbb Q(i)$, so I restrict to show that $\sqrt[4]{-5}\notin \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)$.

Assume for a contradiction that $\sqrt[4]{-5}\in \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)$. Then there exist $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Q$ such that $\sqrt[4]{-5} = a + ib + \sqrt 5 c + \sqrt{-5}d$. Hence we calculate
$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{-5} &= (\sqrt[4]{-5})^2 = (a+ib +\sqrt5c+\sqrt{-5}d)^2\\
&= a^2-b^2+5c^2-5d^2 + i(ab+5cd) + \sqrt{5}(ac-bd) + \sqrt{-5}(ad+bc).
\end{align*}
$$
From this we get the following four equations:

$$ \begin{gather}
 a^2-b^2 +5c^2-5d^2 = 0 \tag{1}\\
 ab+5cd=0\tag{2}\\
 ac-bd=0\tag{3}\\
 ad+bc=1\tag{4}\\
\end{gather}$$
Now, we show that $a,b,c,d\neq 0$: If $a=0$, then (4) implies $b,c\neq 0$ and hence $d=0$ by (3). But then (1) says $-b^2+5c^2=0$ or equivalently $5 = (b/c)^2$ which is a contradiction to $\sqrt{5}\notin \mathbb Q$. Hence $a\neq 0$. Quite the same argument shows that $b,c,d\neq 0$.

Multiplying (2) by $d$ and substituting $ac = bd$ (by (3)), we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
0 = abd+5cd^2 = a^2c + 5cd^2 = c(a^2+5d^2).
\end{align*}
$$
Since $c\neq 0$ we have $a^2+5d^2=0$ in $\mathbb Q$. But this is only possible if $a=d=0$, which contradicts $a,d\neq 0$.

Thus, we have shown $\sqrt[4]{-5}\notin \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)$.

Comment: How does showing what you did make it 8??? I don't get this at all...

Comment: I don't get how showing those are strict inclusions would mean it is 8

Comment: This is because $[\mathbb Q(i), \mathbb Q] = [\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5), \mathbb Q(i)] = [\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}), \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)] = 2$.

Comment: I seriously don't understand, we are trying to find $[\mathbb Q (i, \sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q (\sqrt[4]{-5} ]$ but how does what you are showing prove this is 2? I understand everything in your answer besides the very first two sentences!

Comment: Since $\sqrt[4]{-5}$ is a root of $X^2 - \sqrt{-5} \in \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)[X]$, we have $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}):\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)] \le 2$. So we just have to prove that this is not 1.

Comment: But I was trying to find $[\mathbb Q (i, \sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q (\sqrt[4]{-5}) ]$, and not $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}):\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)] $. I think my tower of fields are different to yours and that is why it is confusing me... They may have the same degree value but it is still confusing because I spent hours getting my head around the tower I made on the main post... Please could you help in terms of the ones I made.

Comment: My answer shows you how to work out $[K:J]$ in your notation, since this is nothing else but $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}):\mathbb Q(i)]$. If you don't want to know how to calculate this, don't ask for it!

Comment: Then how come you are considering $ [\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}):\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)]$?

Comment: What has that got to do with $\mathbb Q (i, \sqrt[4]{-5}) : \mathbb Q(i)]$?

Comment: I calculated $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q(i)]$ by considering the intermediate field $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)$. It is easier to calculate $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)]$ and $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5): \mathbb Q(i)]$ separately, than calculating $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q(i)]$ directly.

Comment: So is $$[\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q(i)]=[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}):\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)] \cdot [\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5): \mathbb Q(i)] 
$$?

Comment: Yes, of course. You already used the degree formula for field extensions, so I assumed you know how it works.

Comment: So $$[\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q(i)]=[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}):\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)] \cdot [\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5): \mathbb Q(i)]=2$$ so what does $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}):\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)]$ and $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5): \mathbb Q(i)]$ equal separately? How do you work them out because I find it hard when we are not working it over Q. That is what I'm finding difficult. One of them must equal $1$ and the other must equal $2$ right?

Comment: No, both of them must equal $2$ so that $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q(i)] = 4$. I already showed you that $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-5}): \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{5})] = 2$ and the other is much easier, so you should do it yourself.

Comment: So for $[\mathbb Q (i, \sqrt5 ) : \mathbb Q(i) ]$ so we note that $\mathbb Q (i, \sqrt5 ) = \mathbb (i) (\sqrt5 )$, so all elements of this set can be written as $a+b \sqrt5$ so lets claim that $\{1, \sqrt5 \}$ is a basis. Span is seen trivially. LI: Assume $b \neq 0$, so for $a+b\sqrt5=0 \iff -\sqrt5 = a/b$. Now $a=c+di$ and $b=f+ei$ with $c,d,e,f \in \mathbb Q$. So $$ -\sqrt5 = \frac ab = \frac{c+di}{f+ei} = \frac{cf-(ec)i +(df)i + de}{f^2 +e^2}$$ So compare reals: $cf+de=- \sqrt5 $ which is a contradiction so $b=0$ so $a=0$ so lin indep so it is $2$. Is this correct? Is there an easier way?

Comment: If you want to compare reals, you conclude $-\sqrt5 = \frac{cf+de}{f^2+e^2}$; you missed the denominator. But then you are using facts about the real numbers (or rather complex numbers), which exceeds the scope of the problem. So, another way is to show that $\sqrt5\notin \mathbb Q(i)$ (since $5 = (\sqrt5)^2\in \mathbb Q(i)$ it then follows that $[\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5):\mathbb Q(i)]=2$). So write $\sqrt 5 = a+bi$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb Q$, square the equation and arrive at a contradiction (only using that $1,i$ is a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $\mathbb Q(i)$ and $\sqrt5\notin \mathbb Q$).

Comment: So how do we know $[\mathbb Q (i, \sqrt5 ) : \mathbb Q (i)]$ is less or equal to $2$?